# Deploying web application to Web Logic in localhost, how do I call the app via postman?

Tags: web-services, postman, weblogic

Right now, I have deployment that is supposed to call web service externally on localhost:7001. I know in my body I will add the xml containing the service I need along with username/password for credentials. But actually calling my web app, I'm not sure how to get the endpoint URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can check endpoint in [Weblogic Admin Console](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/weblogic-server/12.2.1.4/wlach/taskhelp/web_applications/TestTheDeployment.html)